When is it fine to put known limiting values into an expression?
$$ \lim_{h\to0} \cfrac{\sin^{cos(h)}(x+h)-\sin(x)}{h}$$
$ \lim\limits_{h\to0} \cos(h) = 1$, putting this in the above expression makes it the derivative of $\sin(x)$ which is $\cos(x)$, and that is the correct limiting value of the expression.
$$ \lim_{h\to0} \cfrac{\sin^{1+h}(x+h)-\sin(x)}{h}$$
This also becomes the derivative of $sin(x)$ if $1$ is put instead of $1+h$, but the correct limiting value of the expression isn't $\cos(x)$, it is $\cos(x)+\log(\sin(x))\sin(x)$.
So, why does putting known limiting values sometimes work, and sometimes doesn't, even when putting them doesn't lead to an indeterminate form?

How do you know what the correct limiting values are in these two examples?

@DavidK Wolfram Alpha

I think the answer to your question is that it is essentially just as difficult to know when the substitution is OK in general as it is to be able to compute the limiting value. WA "knows" how to evaluate the limits and come up with the correct answer. Do what WA does and you will know the limits and can confirm that they are the same as for substituting. It may be possible to determine the substitution is OK before finishing the evaluation of the limit, but I don't think it is likely to save you any effort in the end.

"why does putting known limiting values sometimes work": by "luck".  There is no clean general reasoning justifying it.

I think the following philosophy is the best way to learn this subject ("best" meaning it makes us most likely to do math correctly):
We never change a subexpression inside a limit into its own limit. Instead, we always apply known limit laws.
If we know that $\lim f(x)=1$ and $\lim g(x)=2$ and we're asked to find $\lim (f(x)+g(x))$, for example, it's tempting to think that we "change the $f(x)$ to $1$ and change the $g(x)$ to $2$". But actually what we are doing is applying a limit law: assuming that $\lim f(x)$ and $\lim g(x)$ both exist, we know that $\lim (f(x)+g(x)) = \lim f(x) + \lim g(x)$. So in this example, the correct calculation is
$$
\lim (f(x)+g(x)) = \lim f(x) + \lim g(x) = 1 + 2 = 3.
$$
Notice how this is subtly different from the technically incorrect calculation
$$
\lim (f(x)+g(x)) = \lim (1+2) = \lim 3 = 3.
$$
In simple situations (sums/products/quotients where all the limits exist) this technically incorrect method will give us the right answer; but the problem is that it tempts us to invent fictitious limit laws in other, more complicated situations such as the problem in the OP. Thinking of every such calculation as the application of specific limit laws leads to the most robust understanding in the long run.
